# Coffeescript nested iterations on ruby objects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a Products page with several products. When you click a product a lightbox pops up with that product and a list of related products. When you hover over the list of related products their images' opacity should change. I have this working for the very first product with this script:

```
 $(document).ready ->
   z = $(".related_products_image")
   z.each ->
     relid = $(this).data("imageid")      
     hover = $("#related_" + relid) 
     hover.mouseenter ->
      $(this).css("opacity", 1.0)
     hover.mouseleave ->
      $(this).css("opacity", 0.4)
```

But it only works for the first product. I believe because I have many lists of related products on the page, and I'm not iterating that, so its just picking the first one.

My html/erb looks like this:

```
<div id="product_popup_<%= product.id %>">
        <div class="related-products">
          <ul class="related_products_list" id="related_products_list_<%= product.id %>" data-listid="<%= product.id %>">
         <% @related_products.each do |related_product| %>
         <li class="related_products_item"><%= link_to large_image(related_product, :itemprop => "image", :data => {:imageid => related_product.id}, :id => "related_" + related_product.id.to_s, :class => "related_products_image"), url_for(related_product) %></li>
         <% end %>
    </ul>
```

So I tried creating a nested iteration that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
 i = $(".related_products_list")
 i.each ->
  listid = $(this).data('listid')
  list = $("#related_products_list_" + listid + " li" + " img") 
  list.each ->
    z = $(".related_products_image")
    relid = $(this).data("imageid")      
    hover = $("#related_" + relid) 
    hover.mouseenter ->
      $(this).css("opacity", 1.0)
    hover.mouseleave ->
      $(this).css("opacity", 0.4)
```

**EDIT: The above code works for the first product ligutbox, but again does nothing for the rest of the products on the page.

Comment: Why not just assign a class to the related items and use that in the jquery selector and set the mousenter/mouseleave callbacks directly?  You'd cut out all the middle stuff.

Comment: If they all belong to the same class when you hover over one image, every image in the list would change opacity.

Comment: I think you're safe from that since 'this' in the event handler context is the individual element.